# Handling error for undefined variable in which data comes from database

Tags: php

I have a function which returns array values obtained from a database. If my database contains the required value then these values are displayed and there is no problem. But if my database doesn't have any values, the returned variable is declared as undefined. This error is thrown by php. I need to handle this error in case no value is returned from database without displaying a php error.

One way would be, just writing

```
error_reporting(0);
```

But I think it's bad practice. Is there any alternative way to handle this error?

Comment: Some code would be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

Please use try catch in php

```
try {
    // Do something
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // catch error. We can write error to log file
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: I doubt OP is using anything that throws exceptions.